# 2 lines of corner bevel artifacts

Tags: bevel, artifacts

I'm trying to fix the artifacts in the topology of this beveled corner.
I already have a few corners that look good, but there are still 2 problematic spots with artifacts and I don't know how to fix that.

[image: 2 artifact]

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: hi and welcome! I think you might want to retopo that big ngon into quads

Comment: Hello please share your file so that we try to fix it: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @pevinkinel N-gons can be problematic, but most of the time beveling is stiil possible...  looking at this very narrow corner I guess there are rather issues with overlapping, but the sharp cuts in the corner seem to indicate there's more probably duplicate geometry. The corner looks like it was beveled (higher resolution than the surrounding parts) and then the doubled vertices not merged where the bevel segments came together.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann You're totally right. Looking at the file now, applying the bevel modifier makes a mess of extra vertices in that corner

Answer (score 1):

You are using a much too high *Amount* setting on the *Bevel* modifier for that sharp corner and have the *Clamp Overlap* option disabled. As you can see in *Wireframe* mode this creates overlapping geometry which is responsible for the artifacts:

[image: bevel overlapping]

So you either have to reduce the *Amount* until the overlapping doesn't occur anymore or enable the *Clamp Overlap* option, so every bevel is reduce to the mutual minimum on all edges so that no overlapping appears, no matter how high the *Amount* is set:

[image: clamp overlap]

Another thing you could do is to make the edge segments somehow wider or create different angles to reduce overlapping, but that depends on how you want the shape of the corner to look like.